# Compare two schema (column name + nullable) in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know how to compare two lists in Scala using `zip` + `forall`.

My question is how do we compare two `DataFrame` schemas. That is, we want to match column names with their nullable property.

My idea is to use hash map to store {column name: nullable}, and do the comparison. I guess it works, but is there any other idiomatic way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should retrieve the elements you want to compare as Tom Lous said in his answer:

```
val s1 = df1.schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.nullable))
val s2 = df2.schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.nullable))
```

Then you can just make use of the `diff` method from Lists, which will return the differences, if that method returns and empty list, then there is no difference, otherwise there is:

```
s1.diff(s2).isEmpty
```

returns: true if no difference was found, false otherwise

Consider that the diff method returns no difference when a field is present in one list but not in the other one. So you may need to attach a second condition to compare lengths

```
s1.diff(s2).isEmpty && s1.length == s2.length
```

Comment: Be aware that for nested schemas the order is compared as well. Generated schemas are alphabetically ordered, so in case you write one manually, it should be ordered the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `zip` & `forall` if you are certain that the amount of columns & order is the same. Or am I missing something?

Anyway I guess this would be the way to do that:

```scala
val s1 = df1.schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.nullable))
val s2 = df2.schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.nullable))

val res = s1 zip s2 forall {
  case ((f1, n1), (f2,n2)) => f1 == f2 && n1 ==  n2
}
```

You could even sort the `s1` & `s2` to make sure field names align, but it still feels tricky.

Otherwise I'd use the `diff` method. Caveat this is a one-sided perspective. Missing fields that do exist in df2 are ignored

```scala
val res = (s1 diff s2).length == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare two schemas, in principle, you just need to compare them as usual:

```
val equal: Boolean = (s1 == s2)
```

However, since you are asking, I suppose that you are having some sort of trouble involving `nullable`, which is something common if you are using Parquet. I explain:

When you are using Parquet, event though the schema is present in the Parquet file, Spark ignores `nullable` when you read the Parquet file, setting them all to `true`. This way, the schema of the Parquet file just before you write it down may not match exactly the schema just after you read in the very same Parquet file. This is not a bug, it is documented feature.

In the example below, I compare two schemas recursively, ignoring the `nullable` setting.

> Technically, this is not exactly what you asked, but you can adjust the code easily. Just adjust the line marked by `//-- comparison`.

```scala
package object my.spark.utilities.schema {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

  implicit class StructTypeExtension(schema: StructType) {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField 

    implicit def similar(other: StructType): Boolean = _similar(schema, other)

    private final def _similar(_this: StructType, _other: StructType): Boolean =
      if(_this.fields.size != _other.fields.size) false
      else
        (_this.fields zip _other.fields)
          .forall { case (t, o) => _similar(t, o) }

    private final def _similar(_this: StructField, _other: StructField): Boolean =
      if((_this.dataType.typeName == "struct") && (_other.dataType.typeName == "struct"))
        _similar(_this.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType], _other.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
      else
        (_this.name == _other.name) && (_this.dataType == _other.dataType) //-- comparison
  }
}
```

Then find whether or not schemas are similar:

```scala
import my.spark.utilities.schema._
val similar: Boolean = s1.similar(s2)
```